# Sharp edge with HTML and CSS only

Tags: html, css

It's much more easy to explain what I'm trying to achieve by showing you an example.

```css
    div{
        width:100px;height:100px;
        border:3px solid #900;
        border-radius:0px 0px 140px 0px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div></div>
```

I want to draw a sharp, direct line(point-to-point) between top-right and bottom-left corners. How do I do this with border-radius?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make a half circle?

Comment: @disinfor No. I'm trying to draw a line between two edges: top-right and bottom-left

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Does it have to be with border-radius?

Comment: @disinfor Done.

Comment: @cale_b Preferably, yes

Comment: @lippr check answer if it's what you want.

Comment: Answer: you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to make a right triangle with a border?

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 182px 182px 0 0;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: -195px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Admittedly, this is is a bit of a wacky way to get to what you're after, as it requires some precise manipulation to look correct - though it's one way, using only CSS, to achieve your goal.

Comment: @lippr - this is the solution I had in mind when I asked "does it have to be with border radius?", and you said yes - yet you've accepted this answer.  (@santi - props to you, I think this is a creative solution that works well)

Answer (score 2):

Is this your desired result.. Kinda too much positioning done here.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 3px solid #900;
  border-left: 3px solid #900;
  position: absolute;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 144px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #900;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 47px;
  left: -23px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider SVG as a viable solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SVG demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 0,100" style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:3;" />
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #900;
  border-radius: 140px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: If you want it to be more of a rectangle, then changed the border-radius from 140px to less.